# Git Bash not showing in my Github Desktop

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I don't see my Portable GitBash in Github Desktop.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DyaN.png)

I already gave some environment variables and I can work on it from cmd or PowerShell, but I wand directly.
[My local PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMDSO.png)
My Path is:
C:\Users\dokmi\Desktop\PortavleGit\bin
And ...\PortableGit\cmd

Comment: Could you please add your local PATH as text as well in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because `Github Desktop` **ONLY** scan the **default path** of `Git`:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

Comment: So it seems like I can't do this because of no admin rights :/